# Table + Error 9 (Subscript out of range)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm using tables to get data from a textbox :
Each line of the textbox = one line of the table_result_final.

I want to get rid of the blank lines in the textebox:

line 1 : ""

line 2 : "TEXT"

line 3 : "TEXT"

line 4 : ""

The problem is, when none of my lines are empty, i get at an error message at the end "Subscript out of range". Though, all of my datas have been collected in the right sheet. I'd like to get rid of it but do not understand the problem :(

Thanks for helping.

```
While Table_Result_Final(i) <> ""

Sheets("IDENREG_FORM_TEXTBOX").Cells(j, 1).Value = Table_Result_Final(i)
i = i + 1
j = j + 1

Wend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to loop through your array index range:

```
For i = LBound(Table_Result_Final) To UBound(Table_Result_Final)
    If Table_Result_Final(i) <> "" Then
        j = j + 1
        Sheets("IDENREG_FORM_TEXTBOX").Cells(j, 1).Value = Table_Result_Final(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Daaaaaaaaaaaamn, I tried this but my code was wrong. What does "Lbound' means pls? Thanks anyway it works like a charm. Have a good day sir

Comment: You are welcome. LBound() gets the "Lower" bound of an array; it's the _brother_ of UBound(), who takes care of the "Upper" bound

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop condition should be:

```
While Table_Result_Final(i) <> "" And i <= UBound(Table_Result_Final)
```

Comment: this would not solve the problem since `Table_Result_Final(i)` would still be evaluated after the iteration with `i = UBound(Table_Result_Final)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a textbox called `txtBox` like this:

[image]

Then, if you run this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemoveEmptyLines()

    Dim strTextBox          As String

    strTextBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("txtBox")).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text

    Debug.Print "Input:"
    Debug.Print strTextBox

    '   We need to make it actually 2 times, just in case if the lines are
    '   odd number.

    strTextBox = Replace(strTextBox, Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10), Chr(10))
    strTextBox = Replace(strTextBox, Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10), Chr(10))
    strTextBox = Replace(strTextBox, Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10), Chr(10))

    Debug.Print "Output:"
    Debug.Print strTextBox


End Sub
```

You will get this in the immediate window:

```
Input:
My name is

tsaka tsaka



Slim Shaddy

....
Output:
My name is
tsaka tsaka
Slim Shaddy
....
```

The idea is to read the text in the textbox and to replace it the `Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10)` which is the chr code for an empty line in a string.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I appreciate it. I picked another answer tho.